# Buffer Zone Algorithm

Tags: google-maps, buffer, algorithm, php

I use google maps, php, mysql, and I want to create a buffer zone in line among some points.

Could someone tell me where can i find the algorithm (php library or the math in order to implement it) to achieve this?

In the forum I read a lot of similar questions based on postgis and the ST_BUFFER function, i want to implement this function in php or javascript with points of google maps.

Comment: Generating a Cartesian buffer about a single point is a trivial exercise. Once you start generating multiple overlapping spheroidal buffers, you really want to be using a code library, not re-inventing that particular wheel.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to re-implement the wheel, there are lots of geospatial libraries out there.
As you've noticed, PostGIS includes a buffer function, unfortunately MySQL has sub-standard spatial support and therefore doesn't include one. If possible you may wish to consider switching to PostGIS if spatial functionality is important to you.

There are several PHP Geospatial libraries list here for various things:
http://phptrends.com/dig_in/geospatial

A search for "Javascript geospatial library" also brings up a few results. One of them is something called jQuery Geo: http://www.jquerygeo.com/

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the answer, in case that anyone else has the same problem be informed that i solved my problems using the geoPHP library!

Answer (score 0):

To compute the buffer on the client side, you could use [JSTS](https://github.com/bjornharrtell/jsts) and [its buffer function](http://bjornharrtell.github.io/jsts/doc/api/symbols/jsts.operation.buffer.html). See the example [here](http://bjornharrtell.github.io/jsts/examples/buffer.html).

On the server side, it seems [MySQL extension for spatial data](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-extensions.html) also has [a buffer function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-operator-functions.html#function_buffer).

If you need to compute high distance buffers, be aware [the projection matters](http://www.esri.com/news/arcuser/0111/geodesic.html).